# How i cant iterate a json object in power apps without use power automate

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I have a custom connector with microsoft graph api in my power apps and i have a request and a response with graph explorer, now my problem is they i can't iterate the object in my power apps table.

**OnSelect code:**
`UpdateContext({getrols:graph_demo.GetRols()})`

[Issue shown in PowerApps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJthh.png)

[View of API Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrVOR.png)

Comment: Try adding a `.value` after the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try adding `.value` to the end of your formula. You'd likely then add `.appRoles` to `.value` to get into the nested JSON.

When in doubt, add a `.` to your formula and leverage the IntelliSense to explore your response schema.

Something like: `ClearCollect(coRols, graph_demo.GetRols().value.appRoles)`

Also, try using a Gallery to show the response instead of a ListBox. Set the Gallery `Items` property to `colRols`.